# SQL search to get last value in every unique single/group entry with same UserID? Entries can occure at different location in the dataset

Tags: sql, sqlite

This is my first post.

I have a table with lets say 3 fields `(Id, UserID, Amount)` and some data in it. [Here is a sample table with some data in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNxOB.png). 
My problem is that I need to get `UserID` and its last amount for every appearance like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juESu.png). It can be several `UserID` in one table, amount is increasing with one, but sometimes two. I'm using `Sqlite`.

Comment: Are you sure the expected answer in the second image is correct? You've said you want to retrieve the latest record for each combination but your expected answer does not reflect that and has duplicated records in it.

Comment: which database you are using?

Comment: Jose i tried to change the question to clarify. The solution Vignesh Kumar A provided did answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `LEAD()`

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=eea2470c15545fb71e4de81ae144d52f)**

```
SELECT ID, UserID, AMOUNT FROM
(
   SELECT ID, UserID, Amount,
       CASE WHEN LEAD(UserID) OVER(ORDER BY ID) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE LEAD(UserID) OVER(ORDER BY ID) END RN
   FROM TABLE1 
) X WHERE UserID <> RN OR RN = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the correct answer. Although, it is not the answer you expected as per my comment below your question.

```
select
    a.ID,
    a.UserID,
    b.Amount
from
    (
        select
            UserID,
            max(ID) as ID
        from
            YOUR_TABLE
        group by
            UserID
    ) a
inner join YOUR_TABLE b on a.ID = b.ID and a.UserID = b.UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

> We can achieved it by creating a group id (changeinorder[col]) 
>   base on the ordering of UserID by detecting if there is a changes from current to previous rec

```
 SELECT *,0 as changeinorder,LAG(Userid) 
           OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS 'Previous Record' INTO #TestB FROM #test
```

[Output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsQkq.png)

```
DECLARE @a INT 
      SELECT @a = 0 

      UPDATE #testB SET Changeinorder =@a, @a=
          CASE WHEN Userid=[Previous Record]
           THEN  @a   ELSE @a+1 END
```

[Output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTJPf.png)

```
  SELECT MAX(ID),UseriD,MAX(Amount) FROM #testB GROUP BY UseriD,changeinorder
```

[Final Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4OYg.png)